# How do you translate and scale a view without the transforms from conflicting with each other?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to translate and scale a UIView from the center of the screen to the upper right corner.

```
 _____________________________
|                            |
|                            |
|         _________          |
|        |         |         |    START
|        |         |         |
|        |_________|         |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|


 _____________________________
|                       __   |
|                      |__|  |
|                            |
|                            |    END
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|
```

I verified that my individual calculations for scale and translation were accurate. But once they are put together, they conflict with each other. The following code makes the view end up too close to the center.

```
CGFloat finalPadding = 10.0f;
CGFloat finalScale = 46.0f / 170.0f;
CGFloat finalX = self.view.frame.size.width 
    - self.platformProgressView.frame.size.width * finalScale 
    - finalPadding;
CGFloat finalY = finalPadding;
CGFloat deltaX = finalX - self.platformProgressView.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat deltaY = finalY - self.platformProgressView.frame.origin.y;

[UIView
    animateWithDuration:1.0
    delay:1.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
    animations:^(void){
        self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY),
            CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScale, finalScale)
        );            
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }
];
```

Final effect:

```
 _____________________________
|                            |
|                            |
|                __          |
|               |__|         |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|
```

Changing the order of the multiplication causes the view to veer off the right edge of the screen.

```
self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(
     CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScale, finalScale),
    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY)
);
```

Final effect (projected):

```
 _____________________________
|                            |
|                            |    __
|                            |   |__|
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|
```

Applying them seperately causes an abrupt jump and the final position is even worse.

```
self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY);
self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScale, finalScale);
```

Final effect:

```
 _____________________________
|                            |
|                            | 
|                            |  
|                            |
|       __                   |
|      |__|                  |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not sure if the system will notify you, so I'm writing this comment to make sure you get a ping.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Understanding transforms

The main thing to realize is that the origin for transforms is the center point of the view rectangle. This is best shown with an example.

First we translate the view. v1 is the view at it's original position, v2 is the view at its translated position. p is the padding that you desire (`finalPadding` in your code). c marks the center point of the view.

```
+--------------------------------+
|                        ^       |
|                        | p     |
|                        v       |
|              +- v2 --------+   |
|              |             |   |
|              |      c      |<->|
|              |             | p |
|              +-------------+   |
|                                |
|                                |
|    +- v1 --------+             |
|    |             |             |
|    |      c      |             |
|    |             |             |
|    +-------------+             |
|                                |
+--------------------------------+
```

Next we scale the view. v3 is the view at its scaled position. Note how the center point for v3 remains unchanged while the dimensions of the view around it shrink. Although the dimensions are correct, the positioning of the view and the resulting padding p' are wrong.

```
+--------------------------------+
|                       ^        |
|                       | p'     |
|                       |        |
|                       v        |
|                 +- v3 --+      |
|                 |   c   |<---->|
|                 +-------+  p'  |
|                                |
|                                |
|    +- v1 --------+             |
|    |             |             |
|    |      c      |             |
|    |             |             |
|    +-------------+             |
|                                |
+--------------------------------+
```

### A fix for the delta calculations

Now that we know how scaling works, we need to fix the code where you calculate the translation deltas. Here is how to do it right:

```
CGRect windowFrame = self.window.frame;
CGRect viewFrame = self.platformProgressView.frame;
CGPoint finalCenter = CGPointZero;
finalCenter.x = (windowFrame.size.width
                 - (viewFrame.size.width * finalScale) / 2.0f
                 - finalPadding);
finalCenter.y = (finalPadding
                 + (viewFrame.size.height * finalScale) / 2.0f);
CGPoint viewCenter = self.platformProgressView.center;
CGFloat deltaX = finalCenter.x - viewCenter.x;
CGFloat deltaY = finalCenter.y - viewCenter.y;
```

### Order of transforms

Finally, as you have noted yourself, the order in which transformations are concatenated with `CGAffineTransformConcat` matters. In your first attempt you have the sequence 1) transform + 2) scale. The result is that the scale transform - which comes later in the sequence - affects the deltas specified for the translate transform.

There are 2 solution here: Either your own second attempt, where you reverse the sequence so that it becomes 1) scale + 2) transform. Or you use the helper function which I suggested in the first revision of my answer. So this

```
self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(
    CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScale, finalScale),
    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY)
);
```

is equivalent to

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeScaleTranslate(CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy, CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy)
{
  return CGAffineTransformMake(sx, 0.0f, 0.0f, sy, dx, dy);
}

self.platformProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScaleTranslate(finalScale, finalScale, deltaX, deltaY);
```

### A different solution: Setting the anchor point

If you're unhappy about the center point being the origin for the view's transforms you can change this by setting the `anchorPoint` property of the view's CALayer. The default anchor point is at 0.5/0.5, which represents the center of the view rectangle. Obviously, the anchor point is not a coordinate but a kind of multiplication factor.

Your original calculation for the translation deltas was correct if we assume that the anchor point is in the upper-left corner of the view. So if you do this

```
self.platformProgressView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)
```

you can keep your original calculations.

### Reference

There is probably a lot more of information material out there, but the WWDC 2011 video [Understanding UIKit Rendering](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_121__understanding_uikit_rendering.m4v) is something that I recently watched and that greatly helped me improve my understanding of the relationship between bounds, center, transform and frame.

Also, if you are going to change the CALayer `anchorPoint` property, you should probably read the property documentation in the [CALayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) first.

Comment: The sets the scale and translate matrix items directly [Link to the source](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/couple-cgaffinetransform-goodies.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this saves a line of code only and does not produce a different result that creating the two transforms individually and concatenating them. Yep, I actually ran my code example and the above code and all six matrix elements (a,b,c,d,tx,ty) were identical.

Comment: The center solution worked. The anchor point solution had little effect.

Comment: Hi @herzbube, Can you help in my Question, I'm stuck in this from past 2 days, Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771275/duet-merge-2-videos-side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

Transformations apply to all previous transforms. So one must take this into account and carefully consider the order.

The values need to be configured as-if one occurs and then the next even though they are concatenated into one transform.

Comment: I needed to do both at the same time for a flying away effect.

Comment: You can create one transform by combining them with the `concat` method, then apply the combined transform. But the calculations for the transforms are the same as if each is done and then the other.

Comment: I don't understand how your code is effectively different from my code. You assigned the scale and translate to local variables and then assigned their concatenation to a third local variable. My code just does it all in one command without creating extra variables.

Comment: It is not effectively different. I was answering the statement: "I needed to do both at the same". The values need to be configured  as-if one occurs and then the next.

Comment: I don't follow you. You're saying `x = matrix0 * matrix1` will not work, while `y = matrix0; z = matrix1; x = y * z;` will work.

Comment: Hi @zaph, Can you help in my Question, I'm stuck in this from past 2 days, Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771275/duet-merge-2-videos-side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

That was a great answer, here is how to do it in Swift 4

```
 let containerFrame: CGRect  = self.view.frame
    let viewFrame: CGRect  = self.containerView.frame
    var finalCenter: CGPoint  = CGPoint.zero
    let finalPadding: CGFloat  = 0
    let finalScale: CGFloat  = 2.0 //whatever scale that you want

    finalCenter.x = (containerFrame.size.width - (viewFrame.size.width * finalScale) / 2.0 - finalPadding)
    finalCenter.y = (finalPadding + (viewFrame.size.height * finalScale) / 2.0);

    let containerCenter: CGPoint  = self.containerView.center
    let deltaX: CGFloat  = finalCenter.x - containerCenter.x
    let deltaY: CGFloat  = finalCenter.y - containerCenter.y

    let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: finalScale, y: finalScale)
    //MARK: changing the deltas for positive to negative values will change the origin x and y of the transformed view
    let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -deltaX, y: deltaY)

    self.containerView.transform = scale.concatenating(translation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotate and Translate:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let yPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if yPos < 0 {
        let scaleX = ((yPos * -1) / 200) + 1
        let translateY = yPos / 2
        var commonTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        commonTransform = commonTransform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: translateY)
        commonTransform = commonTransform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleX)
        self.customView?.transform = commonTransform
    }else{
        self.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be relevant to this post

Comment: OK going to Del. Sorry