# Duet - Merge 2 Videos Side by Side

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4.2

**NOTE:-** Merge Videos Side By Side WITHOUT Losing Video Quality

I think that is a **Very Very Important** Question, After a lot of searches & Googling, didn't find any helpful material related to this Question.

I'm working on a Project where I need to MERGE Videos Side-By-Side in a single file.

I had done **Merged Videos using AVFoundation** But the problem is FIRST Video is showing as an Overlay to a SECOND video(not Merging properly as same as **SMULE App/Karaoke App or Tiktok App**).

```
func mergeVideosFilesWithUrl(savedVideoUrl: URL, newVideoUrl: URL, audioUrl:URL)
    {
        let savePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/camRecordedVideo.mp4")
        do { // delete old video
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl as URL)
        } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }

        var mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        var mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        let aNewVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: newVideoUrl)
        let asavedVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: savedVideoUrl)

        let aNewVideoTrack : AVAssetTrack = aNewVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let aSavedVideoTrack : AVAssetTrack = asavedVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

        let mutableCompositionNewVideoTrack : AVMutableCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
        do{
            try mutableCompositionNewVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aNewVideoAsset.duration), of: aNewVideoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        }catch {  print("Mutable Error") }

        let mutableCompositionSavedVideoTrack : AVMutableCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
        do{
            try mutableCompositionSavedVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: asavedVideoAsset.duration), of: aSavedVideoTrack , at: CMTime.zero)
        }catch{ print("Mutable Error") }

        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: CMTimeMaximum(aNewVideoAsset.duration, asavedVideoAsset.duration) )

        let newVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: mutableCompositionNewVideoTrack)
        let newScale : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
        let newMove : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 230, y: 230)
        newVideoLayerInstruction.setTransform(newScale.concatenating(newMove), at: CMTime.zero)

        let savedVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: mutableCompositionSavedVideoTrack)
        let savedScale : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.5)
        let savedMove : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        savedVideoLayerInstruction.setTransform(savedScale.concatenating(savedMove), at: CMTime.zero)

        mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [newVideoLayerInstruction, savedVideoLayerInstruction]


        mutableVideoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1240 , height: self.camPreview.frame.height)

        finalPath = savePathUrl.absoluteString
        let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        assetExport.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

        assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl as URL
        assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            switch assetExport.status {

            case AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed:
                print("success")
            case  AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSession.Status.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
            default:
                print("complete")
            }
        }

    }
```

**And this is my Output**
[image]

**And what I want**

[image]

As I don't know what is the best approach to make a SIDE BY SIDE VIDEO/DUET VIDEO... As for now, I have used AVFoundation. I have not used any 3rd party framework or any POD.

I would like to ask, what is the BEST Approach to implement this? Videos should Merge on Server side or an App?  Also which Approach I should use?

**Any help would be highly highly highly appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: This is a brand new singing plataform project which is beggining - LiveJam. github.com/richardaum/livejam Take a look and consider support us - we are looking expert contributors and you could be one of us.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I would create a new `AVMutableComposition` object containing 2 tracks, and set transform on each to place them side by side:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition(urlAssetInitializationOptions: <your options>)
let videoTrackA = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType:.video, preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid);
let videoTrackB = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType:.video, preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid);

videoTrackA.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: <yourX_for_A>, y:0.0)
videoTrackB.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: <yourX_for_B>, y:0.0)
```

Then. save it using:

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset:<yourAsset>, presetName:<yourPresetName>)
exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: <yourCompletionHandler>)
```

(Swift code not tested).

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you explain me a little bit more? Please

Comment: Can you please Review my Code?

Comment: You should now work on a minimal sample: just add your 2 video tracks to your composition (no 'instructions' layer, no audio). Then, be sure the tracks are added to your composition, export it to a file and open the exported file in Quicktime Player 7. Then, open the `Movie Properties` window (⌘+J shortcut) and verify the properties of your 2 video tracks. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: For 1st Video mutableCompositionNewVideoTrack.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0.0, y:0.0)

Comment: For 2nd Video mutableCompositionSavedVideoTrack.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: self.camPreview.frame.width/2, y:0.0)

Comment: Using above Transform, still getting only 1 Video.. Is there any proper mistake?

Comment: In above code, Scaling is hard coded, It will only work fine in specific scenario. You need to scale up or down both videos in general case.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, `AVAssetExportSession` is for simple needs, and it is too simple for your situation.

You must use [AVAssetWriter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter).

You add [AVAssetWriterInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput) to your `AVAssetWriter`.

You can configure trasnform of the `AVAssetWriterInput` using its `transform` property.

Then, you feed your `AVAssetWriterInput` with CMSampleBuffer (each images buffer) using `append` calls.

See full Apple documentation for detailed example: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH9-SW2

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your width of video frame size (render size), if your frame render width is say 800. you have to translate second merged video to 400, (Half Half). And you similarly you have to scale down or up. as shown in sample code snippet below.

```
        var renderSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 534) // 534
        let assetInfo = AVMutableComposition.orientationFromTransform(firstTrack.preferredTransform)
        renderSize = assetInfo.isPortrait ? CGSize(width: renderSize.height, height: renderSize.width) : CGSize(width: renderSize.width, height: renderSize.height)
        
        let scaleRatioX = (renderSize.width / 2) / firstTrack.naturalSize.width
        let scaleRatioY = (renderSize.height) / firstTrack.naturalSize.height
        
        let scaleRatio2X = (renderSize.width / 2) / secondTrack.naturalSize.width
        let scaleRatio2Y = renderSize.height / secondTrack.naturalSize.height
        
        print("Scale Video 1 : \(scaleRatioX), \(scaleRatioY)") // print("Scale Video 1 : \(scaleRatioY), \(scaleRatioX)")
        print("Scale Video 2 : \(scaleRatio2X), \(scaleRatio2Y)")
        
//        let scale  = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatioY, y: scaleRatioX) // 1, 1
        let scale  = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatioX, y: scaleRatioY)
        let move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

        firstlayerInstruction.setTransform(scale.concatenating(move), at: .zero)
        let secondlayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: secondTrack)

        let secondScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatio2X, y: scaleRatio2Y) // 0.13, 0.13
        let secondMove = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 400, y: 0) // 160, 0
        secondlayerInstruction.setTransform(secondScale.concatenating(secondMove), at: .zero)
```

Comment: can you share a full code for video composition top half and bottom half duet song .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct Function to Create Duet Video in swift and swiftUI

The video Takes two videos and merge it side by side

func combineVideosWithAudio(video1URL: URL, video2URL: URL, outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
// Create AVAsset for each input video
let asset1 = AVAsset(url: video1URL)
let asset2 = AVAsset(url: video2URL)

```
    // Create composition
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    // Add video tracks to the composition
    let videoTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let videoTrack2 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    // Add audio tracks to the composition
    let audioTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let audioTrack2 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    do {
        // Add video tracks to the composition
        try videoTrack1?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset1.duration), of: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: .zero)
        try videoTrack2?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset2.duration), of: asset2.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: .zero)

        // Add audio tracks to the composition
        try audioTrack1?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset1.duration), of: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: .zero)
        try audioTrack2?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset2.duration), of: asset2.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: .zero)
    } catch {
        completion(error)
        return
    }

    // Set up video composition instructions
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: CMTimeAdd(asset1.duration, asset2.duration))

    // Set up video layer instructions
    let layerInstruction1 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack1!)
    let layerInstruction2 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack2!)

    // Zoom the second video within its dimensions
    let zoomFactor: CGFloat = 0.7 // Adjust the zoom factor to your liking
    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoomFactor, y: zoomFactor)
    let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].naturalSize.width, y: 0)

    let combinedTransform = scaleTransform.concatenating(translateTransform)
    layerInstruction2.setTransform(combinedTransform, at: .zero)

    // Add instructions to the composition
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction1, layerInstruction2]

    // Create video composition
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].naturalSize.width * 2, height: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].naturalSize.height)

    // Export the composition to a file
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        completion(exportSession.error)
    }
}
```