# Club Values of array

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an **iOS App** in **Swift 4.2**.
I am geting JSON array which I convert into Swift object of Class **Sector**

**JSON:**

```
"Sector": [
            {
                "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
                "PERC_HOLD": 5.6,
                "CO_NAME": "REVERSE REPO"
            },
            {
                "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
                "PERC_HOLD": 1.0,
                "CO_NAME": "BHARTI AIRTEL"
            },
            {
                "REPSECTOR": "FERROUS METALS",
                "PERC_HOLD": 0.3,
                "CO_NAME": "COAL INDIA"
            }
        ]
```

**Class:**

```
class Sector{
  var REPSECTOR:String=""
  var PERC_HOLD:Double=0.0
  var CO_NAME:String=""
}
```

I am making Array array1 of type **[Sector]** from above.

I need to make a new array from above array which must be clubed/combined values based on **REPSECTOR** variable, and total of PERC_HOLD.

**Expected Result:**

new array with 2 elements:
1: TELECOM - SERVICES, 5.6+1.0
2: FERROUS METALS, 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the array you've decoded is called `array` :

```
var array: [Sector]()
```

Let's create a dictionary of sectors that have the same `REPSECTOR` property :

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: array) {
    $0.REPSECTOR
}
```

Now let's create an new array with sectors that have the same name, and sum their `PERC_HOLD` :

```
var newArray = [Sector]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    let sector = Sector()
    sector.REPSECTOR = key
    sector.PERC_HOLD = value.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.PERC_HOLD })
    newArray.append(sector)
}
```

You could check the result this way :

```
for s in newArray {
    print(s.CO_NAME, s.PERC_HOLD)
}
```

Comment: Sir, please take a look at my Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771275/duet-merge-2-videos-side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should use proper casing in your `Sector` type, and use `Codable`. For your type it would be trivial:

```
struct Sector: Codable {
    let repsector: String
    let percHold: Double
    let coName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case repsector = "REPSECTOR"
        case percHold = "PERC_HOLD"
        case coName = "CO_NAME"
    }
}
```

Then, assuming we have JSON like this:

```
let sectorsJSON = """
[
  {
    "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
    "PERC_HOLD": 5.6,
    "CO_NAME": "REVERSE REPO"
  },
  {
    "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
    "PERC_HOLD": 1.0,
    "CO_NAME": "BHARTI AIRTEL"
  },
  {
    "REPSECTOR": "FERROUS METALS",
    "PERC_HOLD": 0.3,
    "CO_NAME": "COAL INDIA"
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

Then we can decode your JSON like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let rawSectors = try decoder.decode([Sector].self, from: sectorsJSON)
```

And then we can group it by `.repsector` and sum up percentages:

```
let groupedSectors = Dictionary(grouping: rawSectors, by: { $0.repsector })
    .map { (arg) -> (String, Double) in
        let (key, value) = arg
        let percents = value.reduce(into: 0, { (acc, sector) in
            acc += sector.percHold
        })
        return (key, percents)
}

print(groupedSectors) // [("FERROUS METALS", 0.3), ("TELECOM - SERVICES", 6.6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let dicSector = ["Sector": [
        [
            "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
            "PERC_HOLD": 5.6,
            "CO_NAME": "REVERSE REPO"
        ],
        [
            "REPSECTOR": "TELECOM - SERVICES",
            "PERC_HOLD": 1.0,
            "CO_NAME": "BHARTI AIRTEL"
        ],
        [
            "REPSECTOR": "FERROUS METALS",
            "PERC_HOLD": 0.3,
            "CO_NAME": "COAL INDIA"
        ]
        ]]
```

**Codable Sector**

```
class Sector: Codable {
    var REPSECTOR:String=""
    var PERC_HOLD:Double=0.0
    var CO_NAME:String=""
}
```

Convert Dictonary to object array

```
    var arraySector = [Sector]()
    if let array = dicSector["Sector"] {
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            arraySector = try jsonDecoder.decode([Sector].self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Array To Grouping

```
    let predicate = { (element: Sector) in
        return element.REPSECTOR
    }

    let dic = Dictionary(grouping: arraySector, by: predicate)
    print(dic)
```

**Output**

> ["TELECOM - SERVICES": [Sector, Sector], "FERROUS
>   METALS": [Sector]]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but working

```
var newArray = [Sector]()

    oldArray.forEach() { element in
        if newArray.contains(where: { $0.REPSECTOR == element.REPSECTOR }) {
            newArray.forEach() { newElement in
                if newElement.REPSECTOR == element.REPSECTOR {
                    newElement.CO_NAME + element.CO_NAME
                } else {
                    newArray.append(element)
                }
            }
        } else {
            newArray.append(element)
        }
    }
```